# Icons set to represent Wikidata classes (hospital, park, waterfall, prison, school, etc)

Tags: data-request, images, wikidata

I am looking for icons that can illustrate Wikidata **classes** such as:

- [Q16917](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q16917)   hospital
- [Q22698](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q22698)   park
- [Q34038](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q34038)   waterfall
- [Q40357](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q40357)   prison
- [Q3914](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3914) school
- etc

I could use each class' [image](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P18) property, but the image is usually a very detailed picture so using it as an icon would be a bad idea, it would be unrecognizable.

- The icons should be recognizable even at small scale, for instance when used as pins on a map.
- The icons should all be in the same style.
- It would be wonderful if each icon's filename could include the Wikidata QID or at least the class name, for instance `icon-Q16917-hospital.svg`. If not included, I will write the mapping myself and make the resulting set available to all.
- Open license, free to redistribute and modify, if possible no attribution required.
- Ideally the icon set would be produced by a community whose explicit goal is to cover as many Wikidata classes as possible.

*Context: My app shows a map of [nearby Wikidata items](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%0A%20%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Flocation%29%20as%20%3Flocation%29%0A%20%20%3Fitem%0A%20%20%28SAMPLE%28COALESCE%28%3Fitem_label_preferred_language%2C%20%3Fitem_label_any_language%29%29%20as%20%3Flabel%29%0A%20%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FclassId%29%20as%20%3Fclass%29%0A%20%20%28SAMPLE%28COALESCE%28%3Fclass_label_preferred_language%2C%20%3Fclass_label_any_language%2C%20%22%3F%22%29%29%20as%20%3Fclass_label%29%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%23%20Around%20given%20location...%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Aaround%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation.%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Acenter%20%22Point%28138.6%2035.6%29%22%5E%5Egeo%3AwktLiteral.%20%23%20NOTE%3A%20Replace%20with%20the%20longitude%2Flatitude%20you%20want%20here.%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aradius%20%225%22%20.%20%23%20Radius%20in%20kilometers.%20NOTE%3A%20If%20not%20enough%20points%20come%20out%2C%20launch%20the%20request%20again%20with%20a%20larger%20radius.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20...%20and%20without%20an%20image.%0A%20%20MINUS%20%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%5B%5D%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20Get%20the%20label%20in%20the%20preferred%20language%20of%20the%20user%2C%20or%20any%20other%20language%20if%20no%20label%20is%20available%20in%20that%20language.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fitem_label_preferred_language.%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fitem_label_preferred_language%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%7D%20%23%20NOTE%3A%20Replace%20%22en%22%20with%20the%20user%27s%20preferred%20language.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fitem_label_any_language%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20Get%20the%20class%20label%20in%20the%20preferred%20language%20of%20the%20user%2C%20or%20any%20other%20language%20if%20no%20label%20is%20available%20in%20that%20language.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%20%3FclassId.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3FclassId%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fclass_label_preferred_language.%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fclass_label_preferred_language%29%20%3D%20%22en%22%29%7D%20%23%20NOTE%3A%20Replace%20%22en%22%20with%20the%20user%27s%20preferred%20language.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3FclassId%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fclass_label_any_language%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fitem).*

Comment: maybe [this source of public domain mapicons](http://www.sjjb.co.uk/mapicons/) could be helpful but you have to match the wikidata classes by hand

Answer (score 3):

Based on ubahnverleih's tip, and due to the current lack of such an icon set, I created this project:

https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Icons-for-Wikidata

I re-used the excellent [Open-SVG-Map-Icons](https://github.com/twain47/Open-SVG-Map-Icons/network) icon set and so far matched a good portion of the icons to Wikidata classes:

[image: Wikidata icons]

Volunteers welcome!

Answer (score 0):

## The Noun Project is my default for icons:

"The Noun Project is a website that aggregates and catalogs symbols that are created and uploaded by graphic designers around the world. Based in Los Angeles, the project functions both as a resource for people in search of typographic symbols and a design history of the genre." [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Noun_Project)

[Search for Hospital icons](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=hospital)
[Search for Park icons](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=park)
[Search for Waterfall icons](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=waterfall)
[Search for Prison icons](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=prison)
[Search for School icons](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=school)

## National Park Service Icons:

are open source and very well done.
[Map Symbols](https://www.nps.gov/hfc/carto/map-symbols.cfm)
[PDF](https://www.nps.gov/hfc/carto/SYMBOLS/map_symbols.pdf)
[Illustrator](https://www.nps.gov/hfc/carto/SYMBOLS/map_symbols.zip)
[NPS Style for ArcGIS](http://www.nps.gov/hfc/carto/symbols/Esri_style_NPS_2012.zip)

## Maki Icons

[Mapbox Open Source Icons](https://www.mapbox.com/maki-icons/)

Comment: The icons need to share the same style. Searching for each icon individually is not a good idea, because it gives the results come from stylistically different sets. If you know a **single set** that has many of the classes (hospital park waterfall prison school), please write an answer.

Comment: you only added that part about the same style after i wasted my time answering your question. once again, your finickiness in getting your question answered 100% to your liking leaves a bad taste in my mouth. you can pick and choose those icons to match them, but that would take your time which clearly is the most valuable thing in the world to you. i know where lots of map icons are. but not motivated in the least to help you out.

Comment: actually i will answer, but only because i care about the community.

Comment: its not a problem that your requests are so specific. it is a problem that you tend to not think them through when writing your questions and omit certain details that clearly make early responses non valid. next time think your question through a number of times before you ask.

Comment: An "icon set" means they share the same style, otherwise they are not an icon set. That's why your answer surprised me, and I thought "well it sounded obvious to me but it looks like I will have to be extra-explicit".

Comment: all of the noun project is an icon set. made up of icon sets. what is obvious to you may not be to others. clearly not to me.

Answer (score 0):

Wikidata actually has an [icon property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2910).

Drawback:

- As of now only 273 items have it. [See them all](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23defaultView%3AImageGrid%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Ficon%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2910%20%3Ficon.%0A%09SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D).
- Even though a common style seems to exist (black-on-white with rounded shapes and no gradient), it is only used by half of the icons. The other ones either have colors, or gradients, or too many small details.

Merit:

- Having icons in Wiidata makes them very easy to retrieve as part of any SPARQL request.

All Wikidata icons:

[image: All Wikidata icons]